# search an xml file for specific attribute values in testcomplete

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, xml-parsing, testcomplete

I have this one xml file in which i need the value of the specific tag. I am using testcomplete as a tool and using c# script to code it in. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Put *some* effort in.  Just googling "c# xml get value of element" will get you plenty of results - LINQ to XML is probably the nicest solution.  Ask a question when you've got a *specific* problem.

Answer (score 1):

To work with XML files in TestComplete, you can use the following objects:

```
XML DOM objects. You can use these objects to work with any XML file. Working with these objects requires more efforts and knowledge of XML DOM. However, we suggest that you use these objects to work with XML files.

TestComplete’s Storages object. You use the methods and properties of this object to write data to and read it from XML files. However, this object works only with XML files created with the Storage.XML method (such files have a specific format, they include sections, subsections and options). For more information on this, see Section Object. If you try to open an XML file that has another format by using the Storage.XML method, an error will occur.
```

[enter link description here](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75236/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, TestComplete is shipped with an extremely useful Help file that is also available [online](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75299/?st=0). For example, the [Working With XML Files From Scripts](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/75236/) topic explains how you can solve your task in several ways with examples.